# react-native imported(?) function arguments is so weired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My react native project skeleton here

```
-app
  --component
        --LoginScreen.js
  --container
  --styles.js

-index.ios.js
-index.android.js
```

and styles.js....

```
...

export const colors = {
 'green' : '#######'
 ....
}


export const test = () => {
  console.log(arguments);
}

...
```

and LoginScreen.js

```
import { test } from '../styles';

export default class LoginScreen {
  ....
  constructor () {
    test();
  }
....
}
```

so watch chrome debug console...

```
Arguments[5]
  0:DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope
  1:_require(moduleId)
  2:Object
  3:Object
  4:null
  callee:(global, require, module, exports)
  length:5
  Symbol(Symbol.iterator):values()
  __proto__:Object
```

what is this?

imported function always return arguments[5]

I don't know why return that arguments.

I think that this related import? function.

Let me know please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow functions do not bind their `arguments`. If you want to use variable number of arguments in React Native, you can use rest parameter syntax `...` to get an array of arguments.

```
export const test = (...args) => {
  console.log(args);
}
```

The `arguments` object should work with named function expressions:

```
export function test() {
  console.log(arguments);
}
```